# Validating an Azure AD client token in my Delphi rest API

Tags: delphi, azure-active-directory, jwt

I have a Rest API written in Delphi and need to validate Azure Active Directory web tokens passed in by any client (e.g A javascript SPA web client) are valid and for my Azure registered application.

I am able to use jose-jwt to generate my own tokens and validate them. https://blogs.embarcadero.com/delphi-jose-jwt-is-a-powerful-json-web-token-library-for-delphi/
However I cannot work out how to validate an AAD token using the jose-jwt library.

I followed these instructions (https://www.voitanos.io/blog/validating-azure-ad-generated-oauth-tokens/) to manually get the public key from Microsoft's site that matches the "kid" property in the AAD token but how I use this with jose-jwt to verify the AAD token has me stumped. I have tried using that as the secret but the jose-jwt library gives me an error "Key is not RSA key in PEM format".

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Microsoft add a "nonce" to the token header for their application scopes, which jose-jwt does not like. This article explains it all.
https://xsreality.medium.com/making-azure-ad-oidc-compliant-5734b70c43ff

Once I added my own scope, jose-jwt accepted the public key because the header did not contain a "nonce"